# Go memory and allocation management

Tags: go, pointers, memory, slice

1. I am parsing a large amount of `Entity` containers from strings/rows returned from a `bufio.Scanner`

   ```
   type Entity struct {
     <primitives_fields>
     <enum_fields>
   }
   ```

   into a slice of their pointers

   ```
   var entities []*Entity

   for scanner.Scan() {
     entity := &Entity{
       <serialize_strings>
     }

     entities = append(entities, entity)
   }
   ```
2. I need to pass this `entities` slice into a specific data structure

   ```
   type Datastructure struct {
      items []*Item
      <auxiliary_fields>
   }
   ```

   generating and storing `len(entities)` amounts of `Item` objects:

   ```
   type Item struct {
     entity *Entity
     <auxiliary_fields>
   }
   ```

   with the pointer to their respective `Entity`:

   ```
   func (ds *Datastructure) Generate(entities []*Entity) {
     ds.items = make([]*Item, len(entities))

     for idx, entity := range entities {
       ds.items[idx] = &Item{
         entity,
         ...
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   to match against another data set of `Other` containers.

   - ***The `entities` slice in step 1. is neither used, nor referenced explicitly any further in code after passing it to the data structure.***
3. The data structure returns `Matches`:

   ```
   type Match struct {
     entity *Entity
     other *Other
   }
   ```

   *through a `channel`*, where some 30% of the `items` will be returned having a match with one of the `Other`.

   - ***The data structure in step 2. is neither used, nor referenced explicitly any further in the code after matching is done.***
4. These `Match` containers are accumulated into a slice of their pointers:

   ```
   var matches []*Match
   ```

   and used for further, heavy computations.

---

This is an in-memory service and I would like to understand where and why references to the parsed `Entity` types and their pointers are kept throughout this pipeline.

Ideally I would want to only hold those `Entity` objects in memory that are referenced in a `Match` container inside the `matches` slice (i.e. only 30% of those initially parsed), and de-allocate/free the memory occupied by the unused/unmatched 70% of `Entity` objects.

For example, if I `nil` both the `entities` and `items` slices when done with them, and thus removing any further reference to the *unused* 70% of the `entities`, would they actually get garbage collected, and their memory de-allocated/freed?

Comment: @CharlieTumahai added clarification; they are serialized from strings returned by a `bufio.Scanner` and contain primitive data types & enums.

Comment: Any values which are unreachable will eventually be garbage collected. That is the only rule you need to know. If you have slices which contain many values that are no longer needed, then removing them from the slice, or removing the reference to that slice will allow them to be garbage collected. Whether any of this makes any difference at all required you to benchmark your code with real data -- the runtime does exactly what is needed 99% of the time with no extra concern.

Comment: @JimB Fair enough. And much appreciated simplicity, this one rule. But, just as a constructed example: is an object that is no longer referenced, but having a pointer field to an object that is still referenced, unreachable? Not part of the question directly, but a potential pitfall that I hoped to learn about here, directly or indirectly.

Comment: You cannot follow references backwards, so a reference to a live object does not prevent the referrer from being collected. Think of reachability as a directed graph from the global scope, if you can't get to an object from valid code, it is unreachable.

Comment: @JimB thanks again, that graph reference makes sense. I was kinda referring to pitfalls in general, but both your comments solve my question sufficiently for now - happy to accept that for an answer if you'd write one up!